# Can mushrooms spontaneously die?

Tags: mycology

These are called mushrooms I believe, had been growing on my door for a few weeks. It's monsoon here. Last night I took a picture of it and it looked like this [image: Mushroom Last Night]. Today when I woke up it became like this: [image]. All this within 12 hours. I'm pretty sure nobody touched the fungus so I'm inclined to believe this was spontaneous.

Comment: nice door! if you want to prevent mould on a door, the least you can do is infuse it with bleach. I imagine the TV has moss on it and the bath has ducks in it.

Comment: Of the thousands of shaggy manes I have seen ( and eaten most) , I never saw one growing directly on wood , nearly always they grow in grass .

Comment: Those shaggy manes are very fast rotting mushrooms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several fungi that autodigest  their lamellae  to release spores. Yours seems to be one of them. Due to the black liquid they release during autodigestion, they have the common name [inkcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkcap).

As an example, read this Wikipedia article about [*Coprinus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinus) for more details.

Comment: It is said the mushrooms deliquesce when they liquify fairly suddenly. Note that the edible version of that mushroom is always nice until the first gray tones appear in the gills, at which stage they are past their prime and way less palatable... they are only worth picking when completely white and when the mushroom is completely closed, otherwise you have to cut the dark bits off. And there are unpleasant copy cats of the same mushroom so you must ID them well. take the spores of shaggy ink caps, mix them with flour and water in a blender, and throw them around some overturned decayed ground

Comment: Actually the coprinus comatus ( pictured) , gets pinkish before grey. I have eaten them with traces of pink, no problem.

Comment: Actually "shaggy mane" is the common name in US ; inkys and micas are other closely related species.